# Tiatnium base 64 module for image encoding decoding

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

Hi I was trying to encode the base64 string from blob/image file.I was shocked when i came to know that "Ti.Utils.base64encode()" method only works in android but wont give the same string in IOS.So after searching through blogs for getting the solution ,i found http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/blog/post/9546524557/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-base64encode-ios-module#.UUqY2VuPg4U

When i try to run the project by including this module in project its getting error log while building the project for ios.Could any on help.Thanks in advace.

```
    [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED ** 
    [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
    [ERROR] :   Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/postfile.app/postfile normal i386 
    [ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

Comment: did you try manually remove build folder, clean & build, new run?

Comment: `Ti.Utils.base64encode()` works in iOS and android, at least with version 3.0.0 on.

Comment: Hey thanks for replays,i have tried cleaning,removingbuild and recompliled but not use.Josiah Heaser,thaks for your suggestions i have tried Ti.Utils.base64encode() in latest verson (3.0.2) itself,but its returning some unrelavant/uncorrect base64econded string in IOS where as working good in android.

Comment: hi, did you resolve this? I have the same issue now.  Thanks.

Comment: i went buy uploading files approach after giveup for base64 encoding.